# Foursquare API Getting friends checkin History

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, foursquare, checkin

So I've created an app on foursquare and used this [tutorial](http://ryokuweil.WordPress.com/2011/08/29/how-to-use-the-foursquare-API-v2-with-oauth-and-PHP/) to get the user to accept my application for their FourSquare account.

Now I was under the impression after I did this I would be able to access their checkin history. I've tried pulling their USER_ID and used this `$friend = $fsObj->get('/users/USER_ID_HERE');` to get the users information. But when I access their checkins `$friend->response->user->checkins` I only see their latest and most recent checkin. Yet their count is greater then one.

I am assuming there is something messed up with them not being an authorized user of my app yet in their profile->settings it shows them that their account is attached to my app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to access their checkin history! Thanks! :)

Comment: Based off these steps https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html I'm stuck on the "Your server will make a request for" part with https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token
  ?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
  &client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
  &grant_type=authorization_code
  &redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
  &code=CODE

I'm not too sure how to make this request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment the API will only return  venue history for the authenticated use (user logged in).

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/venuehistory.html

I am also hoping to be able to see top visited venues by user at some point soon. Foursq folk, any eta on when we'd be able to get at least a top 10 from any friended user of the authenticated profile?

Comment: Historical check-in information is more of a product change than a technical change, so no ETA on that (or promise that it will ever happen).

Answer (score 1):

To access the authorized user's checkin history, you need the /users/USER_ID/checkins endpoint. The /users endpoint it appears you're using only shows one checkin that's used by the native apps to populate the "last seen at" information.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins.html